# Looping through files only opens first file

Tags: excel, vba

I've read all the answers on Stack Overflow but can't fix this problem.
I'm trying to open each file in a folder, but the Do While loop action correctly opens the first file, performs the task, saves the file and then opens the first file again. How do I get it to go to the next file?

```
Sub loopmacro()
    Dim psheet As Worksheet
    Dim imppath As String
    Dim impfile As String
    Dim exppath As String
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim thiswb As Workbook
    Dim opsheet As Worksheet

    Set thiswb = ThisWorkbook
    impfile = Sheets("LOOKUPS").Range("C13")
    imppath = Dir(impfile)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If Dir(impfile) = "" Then
        MsgBox "There are no files in the PASTE CSV FOLDER"
    Else
        Do While imppath <> ""
            Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(impfile)
            wb1.Activate
            thiswb.Activate
            Call clear_paste_csv_data_sheet
            wb1.Activate
            Range("A1:F1000").Copy
            thiswb.Activate
            Sheets("Paste CSV here").Select
            Range("A1").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            wb1.Close
            thiswb.Activate
            Call calc_data_lines
            exppath = thiswb.Sheets("LOOKUPS").Range("C17")
            Set wb2 = Workbooks.Add
            thiswb.Activate
            Sheets("CNV OUTPUT").Range("A1:A1000").Copy
            wb2.Activate
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            wb2.SaveAs Filename:=exppath
            wb2.Close
            imppath = Dir
        Loop
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the content of  `Sheets("LOOKUPS").Range("C13")` ?

Comment: Hi FunThomas, its a string value that gives the folder where the files are:

Comment: D:\All of Balancing\zz CNV FILE CREATOR\Old CSV to CNV\Paste CSV Files\*.csv

Comment: I see when I paste the link it doesn't add the back slash before the *.csv

Answer (score 0):

This line is only referencing the folder and not the file in the folder:

```
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(impfile)
```

It should be:

```
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(impfile & imppath)
```

This indicates that you've probably got your variable names around the wrong way.
It looks like you should have:

```
impPath = Sheets("LOOKUPS").Range("C13")
```

and

```
impfile = Dir(imppath)
```

then this will read logically:

```
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(imppath & impfile)
```

Comment: Thank you much. Appreciated.

Comment: If it worked feel free to tick as accepted answer. :)